# Stop the blur to work when click on the second textbox

Tags: jquery, html

Its a kind of replica i made to make you understand the problem

In this problem, when i click and focus on the first textbox, the div will appear but if i click on the second textbox without fill up the first textbox, due to blur function the div disappears. I want when i click on the second textbox without filling up the first textbox the div didn't disappear. Is there any way to stop the blur to work when we focus on the second textbox without filling the first textbox. This easy problems take too much time.

Html

```
<input type="text" class="b"><br>
<div class="d" style="display: none;">
I want to disappear
<input type="text" class="a">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".b").focus(function(){
  $(".d").show();
});

$(".a").focus(function(){
  $(".d").show();
});
$(".b").blur(function(){
  if(this.value.length > 0){
    $(".d").show();
    }else{
    $(".d").hide();
  }
});
$(".a").blur(function(){
if(this.value.length > 0){
  $(".d").show();
  }else{
  $(".d").hide();
}
});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: the right way to get the value from a field is `$(".your_input").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small `setTiemout` to wait the event `focus` to be fire on the second field :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".b").focus(function(){
      $(".d").show();
     });

     $(".a").focus(function(){
      $(".d").show();
     });
     
     $(".b").blur(function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
       if(!$(".a").is(":focus")) {
        if($(".b").val().length > 0){
         $(".d").show();
        }else{
         $(".d").hide();
        }
       }
      }, 10);
     });
     
     $(".a").blur(function(){
      if($(this).val().length > 0){
       $(".d").show();
      }else{
       $(".d").hide();
      }
     });
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" class="b"><br>
    <div class="d" style="display: none;">
    I want to disappear
    <input type="text" class="a">
    </div>
```

Comment: good idea, thanks. Just add another if condition in || in both blur function for fill up some text in other textbox.